# How to run a custom function after scheduling an entry in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, hooks

Is there an `org-mode` hook that would allow me to run a custom function after scheduling an entry (i.e. running `C-c C-s`/`org-schedule` in an Org buffer)? I've checked https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html, but I don't see anything that will help. I tried to see if `org-property-changed-functions` would work like this:

```
(add-hook 'org-property-changed-functions
          (lambda (name value)
            (message "%s %s" name value)))
```

It works for properties like "Effort", but not for things like "SCHEDULED".

Is there any other way I can achieve this? I'm using Emacs version 27.2 on macOS with Org mode version 9.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such hook (`org-property-changed-functions` does not apply to [Special Properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) unfortunately), but the other standard method to customize the behavior of a function is to [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html) it and that does apply here. If the custom function that you want to apply is *always* the same, then the simplest thing to do is to call that function at the end of `org-schedule`. Assuming that your custom function is called `my/custom-function`, and it takes the same arguments as `org-schedule` (which you can always disregard if you want), you can add this to your init file:

```el
(advice-add 'org-schedule :after #'my/custom-function)
```

If there are problems, you can remove the advice with

```el
(advice-remove 'org-schedule #'my/custom-function)
```

and try again.

I tested with a stupid custom function:

```el
(defun my/custom-func (arg &optional time)
  (message "my/custom-func was called"))
```

and it seems work (for some value of "work").

Advising a function can get complicated fairly fast, but for simple modifications, the above will suffice.